# Touchpad features, like right click and scrolling with two fingers not working

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

Hello everybody Am new to ubuntu linux and i have ubuntu 20.04 and before this i was using windows 10. In windows i had all the features of touchpad like right click and scroll with two fingers etc. These features were provided by a seperate "Focal Tech.exe" type of driver. I had to install that driver manually. Once installed than everything was okay. Now in ubuntu I don't have those features.I have tried installing drivers like
*apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics*

I have just installed drivers and unistalled or removed all of them except the above one. I have tried to install that "Focal Tech.exe" through **wine** but that also didn't help.

In this link below.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection
I have the **3rd problem**. I also don't have the touchpad option in my ***mouse and touchpad*** settings.

[***mouse and touchpad settings***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKguH.png)

I have [this](https://www.haier.com/pk/pcs/y11c.shtml) laptop. dual boot with windows 10.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: well am sorry by the way. I solved this issue by installing [this](https://github.com/chilledHamza/focaltech-dkms)

Comment: well i use to browse questions but this was my first question.